# Two Honor 9: One gets EMUI update, one does not, how to fix?

Tags: updates, huawei, emui

We have two Honor 9 ordered at the same time. Both not rooted, one has developer mode enabled.

Recently I realized that the phone without developer mode received the EMUI update from 5.1 to 8.0 whereas the other one with dev options did not.
I tried to check for updates, forced downloading all packages, rebooting etc, no luck.

I don't know whether developer mode may affect the updates but AFAIK there is nothing else special on both phones.

Is there something else I could do (except resetting the phone) to receive the EMUI 8.0 update?

Comment: I have seen in forums that clearing Google Framework helps but it [has undesirable consequences](http://www.talkandroid.com/185088-google-engineer-explains-why-you-shouldnt-clear-google-services-framework-data/). Despite this warning , In did that on MiA1 and got the update next day. Another option is using a VPN to log from a different location and that seem to help others but not me

Comment: @beeshyams thanks for the hint, from reading this article clearing G Framework is indeed a little harsh since I have quite some apps relying on GCM. I hope somebody has alternative approaches here. The VPN solution is interesting but strange as both devices are in the same location, at least when obtaining updates over wifi.

Comment: That's the reason I didn't recommend GSF activity, though I tried despite knowing the risk. Maybe things have changed because lots of people claim on MiA1 forums that it worked and no one is complaining ?! There are plenty of free VPN apps do you can try and see if it helps. But I am clueless as to the fundamental reason, developer options shouldn't be a reason

Comment: Though ordered at same time, they may belong to different *batches* and if it is a staged update that could be the reason